# MVC JavaScript's window.open adds to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 and jQuery. I am trying to open an external website. I am using the click event (and not a link) because I have some custom logic that will add values to a query string of the external site it is calling.

The JavaScript `window.open` function is opening a new window, however it is pre-pending the original website's URL to the begining of the external website's URL.

Here is the jQuery code I am using:

```
$(function () {
        $("#btnTransfer").click(function () {
            //custom logic
            window.open('http:\\www.google.com');
        });
```

The new window opens with the URL of:

```
http://localhost:28761/www.google.com
```

Any ideas?

I have tried using `_blank` as the name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your slashes are backwards:

```
window.open('http:\\www.google.com');
```

should be

```
window.open('http://www.google.com');
```

with the wrong slashes it would be interpreted as a relative url.

Answer (score 1):

you url is incorrect. You need to use forward slashes not backslashes.

```
window.open('http://www.google.com');
```